# How do I implement abstract methods with different parameters/return types

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, xcode11

I have parent class called "Item", and child class called "YTListItem". I want to have a functions called instantiate() which will be implemented in each child class, and return a view controller. The type of the view controller will be different depending on which child class is calling the instantiate() method. My issue is that swift does not seem to recognize me overriding the function if it has different parameters or return types.

The error occurs when I override the function, I get the error "Method does not override any method from its superclass".

```
class Item {
    var name: String
    var description: String

    init(name: String = "Test text", description: String = "Test description of the item") {
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
    }

    func instantiate() {}



}



class YTListItem: Item {
    var address: String

    init(name: String = "Test text", description: String = "Test text", address: String = "SivTGfXxYz0") {
        self.address = address
        super.init(name: name, description: description)
    }

     override func instantiate(storyboard: UIStoryboard) -> YTDescViewController? {
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "desc") as? YTDescViewController
        return vc
    }

}
```

Is there a way to do this? I've seen mentions of protocols when searching how to make it work but I'm new to swift so I'm hoping to be able to get through it using methods I've already learned.

Comment: The parameters of a function are part of its identity so making them different in the subclass is definitely defining a different function.  Why do you even want it to exist in the parent (or protocol)?  If a class only knew the parent definition, it wouldn't know how to call the child implementation anyway.

Comment: You should look at generics instead of inheritance

Comment: @PhillipMills I have an array of Item objects, that way I can populate it with YTDescItem objects and the other subclasses that I will create. I am trying to have it so I can take an arbitrary item in the array and use the instantiate() method, which will instantiate different view controllers based on which subclass of Item it is

Comment: That's fine but according to your subclass definition of `instantiate` the caller needs to know which storyboard contains the matching view controller.  Is it going to get that from your arbitrary object?

Comment: @PhillipMills I was planning on passing in the storyboard as one of the parameters, and that's when I ran into the issue of function overriding not working. As a separate note, I was able to find a way to implement the functionality using a switch statement in a separate method, but it feels like this isn't the "correct" way to use oop, so I am still curious as to if there would be a way to make it as I originally wanted. I also probably should have been using polymorphism instead of inheritance for this in the first place.

Comment: If you're always passing in the storyboard, declare it that way in the parent.  That way it will be a true override instead of two functions with sort of similar names.

Comment: You can return a `UIViewController from instantiate function rather than returning a specific subclass of UIViewController and typecast it later if you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I don't think you should be instantiating a ViewController from you model class. Instead you should be injecting your model to the ViewController. But for your particular scenario you can just return a UIViewController from instantiate function rather than it's subclass (YTDescViewController). And I think you should use protocols for your scenario something like this:

```
protocol Item {
   var name: String {get set}
   var description: String {get set}
   var storyboard : UIStoryboard {get set}
   func instatntiate() -> UIViewController
}
extension Item {
   var viewControllerID : String {
       return "desc"
   }
}
struct YTListItem:  Item {
   var name: String
   var description: String
   var storyboard: UIStoryboard
   func instatntiate() -> UIViewController {
      return storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: viewControllerID)
   }

}
```

You can also use associatedType to customize the return type of instantiate (or the parameters) in Item protocol. But in that case you would need to implement type erasures to hold generic reference to class/struct objects that implement Item protocol.